# if window scroll amount -> then reverse back in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 50) {
        $(".class").addClass("bgposi");
        // $(".top").addClass("fixd");
        // $(".logo").addClass("maxwidth");
       if (scroll >= 50) {
        $(".class").addClass("bgposi");
        // $(".top").addClass("fixd");
        // $(".logo").addClass("maxwidth");
        }
    }

});
```

So, basically my class that I'm adding on scroll. `.bgposi` is moving the background image position when I scroll past `50px` on the page using `(window).scroll(function()`. Which works fine, so my first if statement alone.. However, I'm trying to reverse it with another if statement, when the user scrolls back up - this is where I'm failing.. any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct the following in your second if statement:

- Do not nest it.
- Change the comparison operator `>=` to `<=`.
- Use `removeClass`.

---

Change:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 50) {
        $(".class").addClass("bgposi");
        // $(".top").addClass("fixd");
        // $(".logo").addClass("maxwidth");
       if (scroll >= 50) {
        $(".class").addClass("bgposi");
        // $(".top").addClass("fixd");
        // $(".logo").addClass("maxwidth");
        }
    }

});
```

To:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 50) {
    $(".class").addClass("bgposi");
    // $(".top").addClass("fixd");
    // $(".logo").addClass("maxwidth");
  } else if (scroll <= 50) {
    $(".class").removeClass("bgposi");
    // $(".top").removeClass("fixd");
    // $(".logo").removeClass("maxwidth");
  }
});
```

---

You could cache some reused selectors *(doing the lookup once)*, like so:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  var $class = $(".class"),
    $top = $(".top"),
    $logo = $(".logo");

  if (scroll >= 50) {
    $class.addClass("bgposi");
    $top.addClass("fixd");
    $logo.addClass("maxwidth");
  } else if (scroll <= 50) {
    $class.removeClass("bgposi");
    $top.removeClass("fixd");
    $logo.removeClass("maxwidth");
  }
});
```

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  var $class = $(".class");

  if (scroll >= 50) {
    $class.addClass("bgposi");
  } else if (scroll <= 50) {
    $class.removeClass("bgposi");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
}
.class {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 20%;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.class.bgposi {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="class"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Been doing a little too much sass lately, I guess. haha nesting everything.